# Add a button to windows shutdown?: shutdown, hibernate, logoff, and "something"

Tags: windows, shutdown

In the windows menu there are some default actions, each one corresponding with a batch command.

```
shutdown /s /t 0
shutdown /h /t 0
shutdown /r /t 0
```

Is there a way to add a new button to that list, and to start a .bat when clicking on it?

Comment: why a batch file when you have vbs ?

Comment: Well, it could be a .vbs, I don't mind.

The point is to execute something.

Comment: You'd probably have to have the Windows source available in order to do that; to the best of my knowledge, short of recompiling, there is no simpler way to add arbitrary actions to that particular fly-out menu. (At best, you'd need to find source for something like ViStart, modify it, and build what in effect would be a replacement Start menu -- and as far as I know no such source is legally available.) What are you trying to accomplish? That is, in what cause are you asking the question you are? Perhaps there's another way to do it.